# Angularjs load templates with directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that lets me insert a chat component. It loads a template as required.

```
mod.directive('chat', function () {
  return {
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/tmpl/chat/chat',
  }
})
```

But the problem is that the template needs additional includes:

```
.chat
  .chatHeader(ng-include="'chatHeader'")
  .chatLog(ng-include="'chatLog'")
```

Partials:

```
script( type="text/ng-template", id='chatLog')
 .chatMsg(ng-include="'chatMsg'", ng-repeat='chatMsg in chatLog')

script( type="text/ng-template", id='chatHeader')
  h3 Chat
```

How do I load the includes? I used to put the partials in the same file as base chat template but if I use replace: true that's no longer allowed.

What's the standard angular way to load included partials?

Answer (score 0):

Using ng-include as you are is perfectly valid. The issue you are facing is likely because your template partial does not have exactly 1 root element. Here is a plunk with a working version of what you are describing: http://plnkr.co/wy1a3T1UdKOlBQXr9o22